What type of interaction in a π-complex?
From Beyer-Walter Lehrbuch der Organischen Chemie, 24. Ed., P.72:

We have Ethene interacting with an electrophile $\ce{X+}$ with 2 different options:

The short living formation of an π-complex, where the 2 electrons in the π-mo interact with the empty orbital of the electrophile. The arrow pointing from donator to acceptor and this representation is often used for a coordinative/ complex bond.
The short living formation of a carbonium ion with a bond, which could be described as 3c-2e.

Now in Hollemann, Anorganische Chemie, Ed. 102, Coordinative Bond it's explicitly mentioned, that a coordinative bond really can't be distinguished from a covalent bond. What I don't understand then is, what does the arrow in the π-complex indicate? I mean, what should a covalent bond between the center of a double bond/ π-mo and another atom look like? Where's the difference to a 3c-2e bond like in the carbonium ion?
Is the interaction in the shown π-complex maybe a little weaker because the double bond still persist? Then why showing the coordination bond-arrow and not something else, which indicates an directed interaction but which doesn't really form a covalent character like coordination bonds normally do?

This reaction scheme isn't correct.

@Mithoron what exactly?

Well, maybe too elaborate for its own good. But they shouldn't write carbonium ion like it was 3c-2e, when it is 3c-4e - halide also gives a pair of electrons. What they call π-complex and carbonium ion are only mesomeric structures of actual cation; and two names of the same thing which has also electron donation in opposite direction.

Different communities differ in how to represent complexes, for instance with  $\pi$ nucleophiles as Lewis base, and electron density between atoms (see an earlier thread here). To count for each line between two atoms two electrons thus can be misleading:

Grossman, The Art of Writing Reasonable Organic Reaction Mechanisms, 2nd edition (2009), p. 271.
Second, let's extend your question a little bit

[...] what should a covalent bond between the center of a double bond/ π-mo and another atom look like [in comparison to a single bond like $\ce{O-H}$ in water]?

The structures depicted above share noticeable electron density between multiple carbon atoms on one, and a metal atom on the other side.  In contrast to denticity as in complexes with EDTA with up to six coordination sites ($\kappa^6$-EDTA)

(source)
the Lewis donor sites are contiguous and the complex with ethene hence is an example of hapticity $\eta^2$.  In this complex, the electron density between the two carbon atoms isn't enough for an integer bond order of 2 (as in isolated molecules of ethene) because simultaneously some electron density now is shared with the metal bound (i.e. it qualifies as covalent bond as defined by IUPAC's Gold Book).  This is easier to grasp considering electrons' wave character complementary to their particle character.
